# Why do i get the Error cannot post /login using express and passportjs?

Tags: express, passport.js

When i make a post request containing the user data to log in, i get the response: Cannot post /login.

What is really weird about this is that you can see trough logging that the request get processed.

I was using postman and a html form to test and both didnt worked.

When i have a failure in the passport.js file it gets logged.

.

Thats my server.js file (shortened):

```js
const express = require("express");

const cors = require("cors");
const flash = require("express-flash");
const passport = require("passport");
const session = require("express-session");
//app configuration
const app = express();
require("dotenv").config();

const initializePassport = require("./config/passport-config");
initializePassport(
  passport,
  require('./models/User')
)



app.use(
  session({
    secret: "Janniks whatsapp Klon",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
  })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//For accepting post from data
const UserRouter = require("./api/User");

app.use(flash());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyarser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(
  cors() //{ origin: "http://localhost:3000", origin: "http://localhost:3000" }
);
app.use("/user", UserRouter);

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
  sucessRedirect: 'http://localhost:3000/login',
  failureRedirect: 'http://localhost:3000/login',
  failureFlash: true
}),
)
```

and thats my passport-config.js file

```js
const passport = require('passport')
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
//Password handle
function initialize(passport, User){
  const authenticateUser = async(emailORnumber, password, done)=>{
    //Find user with email or phone number
    let user;
    if(emailORnumber.includes('@')){
      user = await User.findOne({ email: emailORnumber})
    }else{
      user = await User.findOne({ number: emailORnumber })
    }
    if(!user){
      //User not found, error
      console.log('User not found')
      return done(null, false, { message: 'Falsches passwort oder falsche Handynummer' })
    }

    //Check if password is correct
    try{
    console.log('Checking password')
    const isMatch= await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if(!isMatch){
      return done(null, false, { message: 'Falsches passwort'})
    }else{
    //If credentials are correct, return the user object
    console.log('correct')        //gets logged
    return done(null, user)
    }
  }
  catch(err){
      console.log(err)
      return done(err)
    }

  }

   passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'emailORnumber'}, authenticateUser)),
  //Serialize user to store
  passport.serializeUser((user, done)=>{
    console.log('Serializing user')              //gets logged
    done(null, user.id)
  })

  //Deserialize user from store
  passport.deserializeUser((id, done)=>{
    console.log('Serializing user')            //dont gets logged but there is no interaction
    User.findById(id, (err, user)=>{
      return done(err, user);
    });
  });

}

module.exports = initialize;
```

Thanks for all awnsers that can be provided!